# Issues with directory in URL?

Tags: html

For my site, I have different directories for different things and for links, I simply add the end with the file name such as "index.html" so it automatically adds it to the end of my url.

When I am in a directory such as "/help" and click on the link that takes me home, it contains the /help so it looks like "www.example.com/help/index.html". How do I make it so it gets rid of the help and just says "www.example.com/index.html".

Comment: Show some code (HTML).

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

`<a href="http://example.com/index.html">Home</a>`

or

`<a href="../index.html">Home</a>`

Depending if you are using Absolute or Relative directories (http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Change the page so that, instead of linking to `index.html`, link to `/index.html`, or even better, `/`